# Trying to translate formula for blending mode

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, opencv

I am using OpenCV C++ for making the blending mode like in `photoshop`, I want to make overlay mode in it. I search its alternate in OpenCV in which I found [this blending](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) way, but its not the overlay as I want to use the overlay method in it.

Overlay method formula from [this documentation](http://www.deepskycolors.com/archive/2010/04/21/formulas-for-Photoshop-blending-modes.html)

```
(Target > 0.5) * (1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5)) * (1-Blend)) +
(Target <= 0.5) * ((2*Target) * Blend)
```

Can anyone please explain this formula for implementation in OpenCV C++ , how I can easily understand it for implementation or is there any *already* build in function for it or any other easy way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for answer and interest but as I didn't found the answer completely following my question , I update my own solution which I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220686/trying-to-translate-formula-for-blending-mode/23222729?noredirect=1#23222729)

First, the author of the link you provided assumed that a pixel color as a value between 0 and 1.

Imagine you want to blend 2 images img1 and img2. The formula says that if a pixel in img1 as a value `Target > 0.5` then the resulting value is `(1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5)) * (1-Blend))` for the blended image where Blend is the value of the pixel of img2.

On the other hand, if `Target <= 0.5` the resulting color value will be `((2*Target) * Blend)`.

You need to do this for each pixel.

This link  provides an overlay blending function with OpenCV.

Here is an example with a grayscale image. For a RGB image, you need to do this for each channel. Of course `img1` and `img2` must have the same size. Maybe there is a quicker way to do it with OpenCV.

```
Mat img1;
Mat img2;
img1 = imread("img1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img2 = imread("img2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat result(img1.size(), CV_32F);

for(int i = 0; i < img1.size().height; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < img1.size().width; ++j){
        float target = float(img1.at<uchar>(i, j)) / 255;
        float blend = float(img2.at<uchar>(i, j)) / 255;
        if(target > 0.5){
            result.at<float>(i, j) = (1 - (1-2*(target-0.5)) * (1-blend));
        }
        else{
            result.at<float>(i, j) = ((2*target) * blend);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find many ready solution in the Internet. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together) following macro is given:

```
#define ChannelBlend_Overlay(A,B)    ((uint8)((B < 128) ? (2 * A * B / 255):(255 - 2 * (255 - A) * (255 - B) / 255)))
```

Additionally you might want to check this package: [blImage](http://www.barbato.us/2010/12/01/blimageblending-emulating-photoshops-blending-modes-opencv/) for source code as you can very easilly translate it. I am sure you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't know how to use these macro's as i seen them before . i didnt understand them well

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Lets break it into pieces:

```
(Target > 0.5) * (1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5)) * (1-Blend)) + (Target <= 0.5) * ((2*Target) * Blend)
```

has two parts that are being blended:

```
(Target > 0.5) * (1 - (1-2*(Target-0.5))
(Target <= 0.5) * (2*Target)
```

Of these the first is making sure that pixels with intensity greater than 0.5 (`Target > 0.5`) only are chosen and the rest (`Target <= 0.5`) go to the other image.
So, the second is limited to 0-0.5 values, which is being scaled to 0-1. For obtaining a similar range for the first set of pixels, a stretching algorithm is being used: `1-(1-2*(Target-0.5))`.

As the documentation mentions, this is a combination of multiply and screen - multiply for pixels with values less than or equal to 0.5 and screen for the rest.

Coming to the point of OpenCV implementation, you will require the following methods:

1. Blend (`I1 *(1-b) + I2 *b`)
2. Addition (`I1 + I2`, with normalization of course)
3. Inversion  (`I2 = 1 - I1`)
4. Thresholding (`I2 = I1 > a/b`)

I have followed the documentation's convention of using 1 as the maximum intensity, you could stick to this using float type images or scale it appropriately to use other formats.